# Temporarily ignore subversion ignore settings

Tags: svn, svnignore

I have a bunch of files that I normally want to ignore so I have the file extensions listed in my global ignore as well as on the folder properties ignore list. However, I have a one-time need to see all unversioned files in my working copy, even those I normally want to ignore. I can't figure out an easy way to do this without clearing out my global ignore, and then removing the ignore folder properties, doing my check, and then adding the ignore property and global string back in.

Is there some easy way to just see a list of (and commit) all unversioned files in my working copy no matter if they should be ignored or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you use the `--no-ignore` flag while doing `svn add` ?

`--no-ignore : disregard default and svn:ignore property ignores`

Try doing something like:

```
 svn add --force --no-ignore .
```

Note that you have to careful about what files get added.

Comment: That sounds like it is going to do what I want. Now I tried navigating to the top level folder and doing: svn add . --no-ignore
I wanted to recursively add all files that are not already in the repository. It gave me an error: svn: warning: '.' is already under version control

Comment: I should have mentioned that I normally do everything via TortoiseSVN. I'm not as familiar with interfacing with subversion from the command prompt. I probably just have my syntax wrong on that command.

Comment: @Shane Wealti - you should only add files/ folders not already in version control, that is unversioned. Don't just give `.`

Comment: My problem is that I want to get a list of all files that I copied into my working copy that are not already under version control and add them. I don't know how to get the list of files and I was hoping I could give a svn command or use TortoiseSVN to add all those files in one step. Otherwise I have to search through all the folders one by one, looking for files that are not versioned.

Comment: @Shane Wealti - Or try `svn add --force --no-ignore .` I have updated my answer as well.